# JavaScript: How to load UI messages from file?

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to JS, so maybe this is an easy question, but I haven't really found a solution. I'm building several HTML forms with JS, which contain user interface messages such as headlines, placeholders etc. I dont't want to hard code these, but rather load them from a file (I dont't need a full internationalization framework though). In PHP I would simply do something like `$msg = parse_ini_file("messages.ini")` and then access them as `$msg["form_title"]`.

What's the equivalent process in JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since JS is run in the browser vs PHP being run on the server you need to make a get request to "fetch" the information. I tend to use fetch since it's making it's way to being a standard.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

So you can either have the data in a plain text file formatted in JSON or you can have a backend like node/express serve up the data.

A typical fetch request with promises would go like this:

```
fetch(
   'http://www.somedomain.com/somedata.json',
   {method: 'GET'}
)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((json) => {console.log(json.form_title););
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks indeed interesting. I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can define all your message in a JSON file and from UI, using ajax request, you can load them in localstorage/sessionstorage during initialization process.
You can easily access data from localstorage like 
localStorage.getItem(form_title)

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery .load function

You'd be able to load only parts of a file if you want

Let's say your div is in index.html like

```
<div class="tofill">Fill me</div>
```

You've got aside content.html like

```
<div class="filler">This is the filling text</div>
```

just call in javascript

```
$(".tofill").load("content.html");
```

you can also use the selector in the load function to get only what you want, like this:

```
$(".tofill").load("content.html .filler");
```

And to get even further, you can grab only what's is inside the filler div like this

```
$(".tofill").load("content.html .filler > *");
```